# Trouble with PI approximation

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to simulate the approximation of pi to 5 decimal places. This is the formula off of which I'm basing it:

[image]

But instead of using infinity, I'm approximating it to 5 decimals. This is the code I have, but the result I get is 0. My speculation is because of the integer division, but I've tried adding 0. to one of the dividens but it doesn't help:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int sum = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {

        sum += pow(-1, k) / (2 * k + 1);

    }

    sum *= 4;

    std::cout << sum;

}
```

This part:

```
sum += pow(-1, k) / (2 * k + 1);
```

I tried changing to:

```
sum += ( pow(-1, k) + 0. ) / (2 * k + 1);
```

or

```
sum += ( pow(-1, k) * 1. ) / (2 * k + 1);
```

But the result is still 0. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Surely `pow(-1, k)` is a totally gratuitous library call...

Comment: Apart from the wrong type for `sum`, note that to compute pi to 5 decimal places with that formula, you need roughly 10^5 terms.

Comment: Better: `sum += (k % 2 ? -1.0 : +1.0) / (2*k + 1)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually, `pow(-1, k)` *is* needed for the approximation to work. --

Comment: @DanielFischer: No. (−1) ^ *k* is needed for the approximation, but not `pow`. That's total overkill.

Comment: @KerrekSB Tab-completion misfired.

Comment: Finally, always try to google first for famous numerical algorithms - there is a great chance it was already discussed, implemented and even corrected -http://www.programmingforums.org/post205410.html.

Comment: Upvote for well-posed question.

Comment: Your not checking for decimal places but *algebraic terms*.  To determine decimal accuracy, you need to subtract previous value from new value.  If the difference is less than 1E-5, you have met your requirement.  The formula you are using may take more than 5 iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare `sum` as `double`.

Comment: `k` is fine as an `int`, that can remain.

Comment: @DanielFischer: ok, I wasn't sure about it